# Problem with KDE programs after upgrading to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, kde

*I experienced this problem with konversation, but while searching for a solution, I saw that many people were having this problem with many different KDE programs, so I thought I'd bring it up here*

I'm running lubuntu (a GTK based distribution), but I run several KDE programs, including konversation. When I was running 14.10, konversation worked without issue, but when I upgraded to to 15.04, I was no longer able to right click and save links. When I tried, I received the following message:

> could not start process cannot talk to klauncher the name org.kde.klauncher5 was not provided by any .service files

How can I solve this problem and be able to right-click and save links again?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**SUMMARY: `apt-get install kinit kio kio-extras kded5`**

---

**LONG VERSION:**

After much searching and experimenting, I was able to find a solution for this problem.

`klauncher` is [a daemon for service activation in KDE and is controlled by](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/klauncher.1.html) `kdeinit` supplied by the `kinit` package. This package was not installed, so I installed it:

> apt-get install kinit

Once I installed `kinit`, the error message went away, but was replaced by another error message:

> could not start process unable to create io-slave klauncher said: unknown protocol 'file'

After some searching I realized I had to install the KDE Input/Output framework:

> apt-get install kio

This solved the problem, but to be sure I also installed kio-extras:

> apt-get install kio-extras

I am now able to right-click and save links without issue. I did still get the following error message when running konversation from the command line:

> Can't communicate with kded_kcookiejar!

Using @[Graham's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/690541/21794), I was able to resolve this issue:

> apt-get install kded5

---

EDITED TO ADD: There still seems to be one outstanding issue. Even though I can save the links, it doesn't remember the last folder I used. Before I upgraded to 15.04, the last folder I saved something to was remembered the next time I tried to save something.

Now, this is not the case. The "Save As" dialog does not remember the last used directory. Instead, it defaults to the directory I run konversation from.

I'm still looking for a solution for this.

Comment: I just updated bug https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=343997 with this helpful info. Thanks!

Comment: And as this seems to be more of a packaging issue (and still present on fresh installs), I have created a bug on the Ubuntu side: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gwenview/+bug/1611510

Comment: Some may also need `pkill kdeinit`. I did, to get `klauncher` to restart: https://askubuntu.com/questions/957109/klauncher-said-unknown-protocol-file-even-though-ive-installed-kio.

Others may require `pkill kded`, but I didn't

Comment: In my case I have an XFCE environment but I've installed konsole (because I love it) and I couldn't save the output into a file. I only had to install kinit.

Answer (score 2):

If it still doesn't work do:

```
sudo apt-get install kded5
```

As well as the other stuff.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I'm less about being pedantic about the functions of this site and more about providing answers for people with problems. If one has a problem with that then they can always change it themselves.

Comment: then you should have edited the existing answer... (You can, you know)  **;-)**

Comment: @Graham: Thanks for that, that solved my problem with remembering the last used directory, and I'm no longer getting kded_kcookiejar errors. I'm going to add it to my answer.

Comment: @Graham: Unfortunately, while my kcookiejar errors went away, it still doesn't remember the last used directory. It seemed like it did for a day, but it no longer does.

Answer (score 0):

**The issue appears to be related to permissions.**
I installed K3B and all related dependencies from the software center.
when I attempted to open the application using the menu icon the application would open and reported the following error:
'' Could not start process Cannot talk to klauncher: The name org.kde.klauncher was not provided by any .service files.''
I closed the application and opened a terminal window.
I typed '' **sudo K3b**'' entered mu password and the application ran without issue. (do not close teh terminal window while using K3B).
I have been running K3b as su and have not had any errors or issues burning CD or DVDs.
CB

Comment: Forgot to add I'm running Linux MInt 18 Cinnamon 64-bit, Cinnamon version 3.0.7 on Kernel 4.4.0-45-generic