# "klauncher said: Unknown protocol 'file'" even though I've installed kio

Tags: xfce

I'm trying to use `kompare`, but when I go to save the file, I'm told that it could not be save. I see

> couldn't create slave: "Unable to create io-slave:\nklauncher said: Unknown protocol 'file'.\n"

in the stderr, and Googling for this problem seems to always be solved by installing `kio`. But I *have* installed `kio`.

Originally, I was getting another error to the stderr, so I followed the instructions at [Problem with KDE programs after upgrading to 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617955/problem-with-kde-programs-after-upgrading-to-15-04). That corrected some of  the error messages, but this one lingers.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit and XFCE

Answer (score 1):

Looks like another little thing I needed was `pkill kdeinit`. That cause `klauncher` to restart.