# How to make KHelpCenter show info-pages, man-pages and information from ScrollKeeper database and make full text search?

Tags: kde, search, documentation, offline, helpfile

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed.

I want to search for documentation and read it off-line (as it is included to the installed packages).

Yelp [does not work](https://askubuntu.com/q/1058947/66509) for this purpose.

So I tried to use KHelpCenter. I installed it with `sudo apt install khelpcenter`.

When I started it, it have various information sources:

- KDE-related stuff
- UNIX manual pages - renders with error:

  > **The requested operation could not be completed**
  >   Cannot Initiate the man Protocol
  >   Technical Reason: Unable to Create io-slave

  [image: man protocol error in khelpcenter]
- Scrollkeeper - shows empty page:

  [image: scrollkeeper empty page in khelpcenter]
- Browse Info Pages - renders with error:

  > **The requested operation could not be completed**
  >   Cannot Initiate the info Protocol
  >   Technical Reason: Unable to Create io-slave

  [image: info page error in khelpcenter]

How to fix all these errors? Do I need to install some dependency or configure already installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems with `info:` and `man:` links are gone after installation of these packages (idea from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/617956/66509)):

```
sudo apt-get install kinit kio kio-extras kded5
```

Then we need to install Oxygen theme to have nice look-and-feel:

```
sudo apt-get install plasma-theme-oxygen oxygen-icon-theme
```

To remove warning `kf5.kservice.services: KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType "QImageIOPlugins" not found` we need to install other package:

```
sudo apt-get install libkf5kdelibs4support-data
```

As the result we will be able to search on 18.04 LTS in Application Manuals (KDE-documentation) and `man`-pages.

KHelpCenter internally use ScrollKeeper's component `scrollkeeper-get-content-list` (located in [`rarian-compat` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=scrollkeeper-get-content-list&mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&arch=any)), so we need to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install rarian-compat
```

To add content to Scrollkeeper category we need to install some application which has documentation in `/usr/share/omf`:

```
 sudo apt-get install synaptic diffuse
```

**But its installation does not help. ScrollKeeper category contains very small amount of objects, their pages fail to render.**

Notes:

1. This instruction seems to be universal for 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS, but in 16.04 LTS we do not have search toolbar.
2. On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS `khelpcenter` has version 4.13, works out the box but does not have search functionality. ScrollKeeper functionality is poor as in newer releases.

**Conclusion:** use Yelp to view desktop documentation (but without full-search).